# Smoothness depends on parametrization

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, parametric

Does the smoothness (meaning infinitely differentiable) of a function depend on its parametrization? Suppose we have the function $f(t) = [t^2,t^{\frac{1}{3}}]^T$ on [0,1]. Then $\nabla f(t) = [2t,\frac{1}{3}t^{-2/3}]^T$. But $t^{\frac{1}{3}}$ is not differentiable at t=0. If I just replaced $t$ with $x^3$, would this make the function smooth?

Comment: It would be smooth as a function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}^2$, but it would be a different function.  The two just happen to have the same image in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: @mathematician But the new function would have similar image and only vary in derivative. Which is what parametrization is typically used for, is it not? At least in some contexts that is the important part

Comment: @Eoin  Right, it is a nicer (smooth) parametrization.  I guess I'm not sure what is actually being asked.